# Make a marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to ask about how to make a double marker in my google map html.
Can anyone give me a suggestion?
Thank you before..
When I click find button, it doesn't show anything in my map

This is my HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PETA</title>
<style>
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map
{
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="panel">
<input id="address1" type="textbox" value="Bogor" />
<input id="address2" type="textbox" value="Bandung" />
<input type="button" value="find!" onclick="codeAddress()" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
var marker1 = null;
var marker2 = null;
var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.275920, 112.791871);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    initialize();
    var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
    gc.geocode({
        'address': address1
    }, function (res1, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert(address1);
            gc.geocode({
                'address': address2
            }, function (res2, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (marker1 && marker1.setMap) marker1.setMap(null);
                    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res1[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                    if (marker2 && marker2.setMap) marker2.setMap(null);
                    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res2[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address2 + ", status=" + status);
            });
        } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address1 + ", status=" + status);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry&callback=initialize">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an error:

> Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map;
>   and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama

indicating that something is wrong with `var map`.

Just set `map` variable as global.

```
var marker1 = null;
var marker2 = null;
var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
```

And inside `initialize()` change:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

to

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Also, remove `initialize()` invocation from `function codeAddress()`, you do not need it.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh6w6kvr/

### EDIT

Here is the full HTML (as you can see, I have moved scripts to `<head>` and removed `callback=initialize`):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PETA</title>
<style>
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map
{
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry">
</script>
<script>
var marker1 = null;
var marker2 = null;

var map;
function initialize()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.275920, 112.791871);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
   // initialize();
   var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
    gc.geocode({
        'address': address1
    }, function (res1, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert(address1);
            gc.geocode({
                'address': address2
            }, function (res2, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (marker1 && marker1.setMap) marker1.setMap(null);
                    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res1[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                    if (marker2 && marker2.setMap) marker2.setMap(null);
                    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res2[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address2 + ", status=" + status);
            });
        } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address1 + ", status=" + status);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="panel">
<input id="address1" type="textbox" value="Bogor" />
<input id="address2" type="textbox" value="Bandung" />
<input type="button" value="find!" onclick="codeAddress()" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested with latest FF, IE and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I had try it and it works with fiddle. But it still doesn't work when I try it in html (via browser)

Comment: Edited answer to include full html.